# What is causing these bugs in the site browsing widget?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

When trying to switch from Stack Overflow to another Stack Exchange sites, I observed this strange sight:

[image]

What's going on here? It looks like some sites logos are switched around, and there's a red-ish looking bar under the Stack Overflow logo. This problems seems to be affecting other sites as well. e.g Code Review:

[image]

I'm running the site on Opera version 49.0.2725.47 on Windows 10 64-bit. I also tried accessing Stack Exchange sites from Chrome version 62.0.3202.94 on Windows 10 64-bit and the site browser looked the same.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome under OSX, my menu looks fine.

Comment: Looks like they modified the icons sprite sheet and either they broke it or you only got an updated image, not the bounding boxes.

Comment: Seems like the length of the sprite image somehow is incorrect, making all the offsets wrong (that red underlined SO logo is in there too). You can view the sprite image [here](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png) (assuming your cached version loads) to look for abnormalities, possibly a part of the image randomly got corrupted (norepro here)

Comment: CSS sprites strike again. Do try to make sure you refreshed the cache!

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.

Comment: I had this happen to me as well, it produced [some rather entertaining hot network questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKUez.png), a hard refresh fixed it for me.

Comment: Happened again -- [Apparently Security.SE is branching out and offering advice on protection against the Imperius Curse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fGMs.png). CTRL+F5 didn't do anything this time on Chrome 62.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's caused by caching on the CDN and the launch of a new site today, [says Adam Lear](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6517941#6517941).

[It should be fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303812/incorrect-icon-in-hot-network-questions-and-communities#comment987723_303812), try a hard refresh. If you continue to see the same problem, please report it in the MSE question.

Comment: Yup. The hard refresh fixed the problem.